# Facebook 404 Keyhash not matched in my Android App

Tags: android, facebook

I have a problem as When I am using the share dialog of Facebook 3.5 Sdk, it asks for the Keyhash which I had generated according to the steps given by Facebook. But when I export signed APK with my previous Keystore then Facebook share dialog returns #404 Keyhash does not matched. I don't know why its happening because we can share from facebook through without Signed APK but unable to share with Signed APK.

Please suggest any solution regarding to the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually when you generate an apk, it uses a different key store than when you're debugging. Both (or more) key hashes must be configured in your app settings. Did you put all the key hashes in your app settings?